# How to run specified Selenese test by maven

Tags: testing, maven, selenium, selenium-ide

I have Selenese with maven and testSuite with a lot of tests, my question how to run some of test cases?

Answer (score 0):

Just like running any specific test in maven:

mvn test -Dtest=(YOUR_TEST_CLASS_NAME)

You can also supply test=TEST_CLASS* for all of that type, etc. Maven has some pretty good name and package matching. You may even be able to run a single test method by supplying the method name (although I have not tried this).

Comment: That does not work, in my pom.xml specified Selenese test suit that contain list of test and when I run tests runs test suite with all tests,  -Dtest= does not help...

Comment: What test plugin are you using? Is it surefire?

Comment: According to this you should be able to run a single test with -Dtest=.... http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2007/06/maven-selenium/

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Selunit](http://www.selunit.org) maven plugin out, it provides include and exclude filters for Selenese suites in the pom.xml configuration.